# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed. Reasons

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

What I did wrong? I tried to swap rs.close(), pstmt.close(), conn.close().
I created a PreparedStatement.
But I still can not display the contents of a database table. If I remove conn.close(), everything works! How close the connection and get an output on the jsp?

This is my code:

```
    public ResultSet executeFetchQuery(String sql) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        conn = Database.getConnection();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PhoneDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
    return rs;
}


public ArrayList<Phone> getAllPhone() {
    ArrayList<Phone> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM phones.product;";
    ResultSet rs = executeFetchQuery(sql);
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            Phone phone = new Phone();
            phone.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            phone.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            phone.setPrice(rs.getInt("price"));
            phone.setQuantity(rs.getInt("quantity"));
            phone.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            System.err.println(phone);
            list.add(phone);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ResultSet rs = executeFetchQuery(sql); 
The above statement closes everything.
```

Actually your code should be 
DBConnection
Iterate through result set 
Store the values/display the value directly(depends on your need)
Finally close the connection. 
Which is the proper way to access the data from db.

Answer (score 0):

The more common pattern for this kind of process is to maintain the connection and the statement outside the main query code. This is priomarily because connections would generally be allocated from a pool as they are expensive to create and preparing the same statement more than once is wasteful.

Something like this is most likely to work both efficiently and correctly.

```
static final Connection conn = Database.getConnection();
static final String sql = "SELECT * FROM phones.product;";
static final PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

public ArrayList<Phone> getAllPhone() {
    ArrayList<Phone> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            Phone phone = new Phone();
            phone.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            phone.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            phone.setPrice(rs.getInt("price"));
            phone.setQuantity(rs.getInt("quantity"));
            phone.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            System.err.println(phone);
            list.add(phone);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        rs.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note how the `ResultSet` is closed in a `finally` block to stop leaks.

There are variations of this pattern which, for example, only create the connection and prepare the statement at the last minute rather than as `static final` fields like I have here.